# customized dropdown value based on foreign key in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

**My Models**

```
class ServicesMenu(models.Model):
   category = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Varient(models.Model):
   category = models.ForeignKey(ServicesMenu, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   varient_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class VarientSubField(models.Model):
   select_Varient = models.ForeignKey(Varient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

so the problem is in VariantSubField, its display something like this.
[image]

here some value are similar i cant change them but i need is to display "category" from ServicesMenu with these VariantSubField dropdown fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize dropdown text, you should implement the standard _ _ str _ _ method in the relevant model:

```
class VarientSubField(models.Model):
   select_Varient = models.ForeignKey(Varient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
   return self.select_Varient.category + " - " + self.select_Varient.varient_name + " - " + self.name
```